# Microsoft Sway Standalone Installation?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

I realize that the conventional way to download sway is from the windows store. Of course I wouldn't be here if that way worked. Unfortunately for me, my windows store on my windows 10 device is terribly bugged and despite many factory resets and tinkering, the windows store crashes every time before it even loads. I think this issue is too big to be resolved given what I have time for.

Instead, I would simply like to find a simple work-around that does not involve the windows store. I would like to just get a stand-alone install of sway and manually place it on my windows 10 device. Here is what I tried:

1. As mentioned above, I tried downloading microsoft sway from the windows store, but my store never loads. Ever. Even after factory resets/OS reinstallations.
2. I also tried downloading sway on my functional windows 7 computer. However this did not work, the [sway page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/sway/9wzdncrd2g0j) has the download button disabled. I guess it recognizes my system as windows 7, and doesn't let me. I'm was rather confused by this, because I never intended to install on windows 7, I just wanted to transfer the set up files for sway. I find it complicated that there are system requirements for simply downloading. I mean, lets face it, even a raspbery pi can download things.

**My question is:** Is there a way to make my 2nd idea work, or should I scrap that idea too?

If I should not pursue the 2nd approach, is there another approach that could work? One thought came to mind:

What if I found a friend who had a functional windows store; could I then download on my friends device, then transfer the set up on my device? I would just try that and test it on my own, but I'd rather not pester people unless I know things would pan out.

Also if nothing will work for my case, just let me know. That's a reality that I'm also mentally prepared for. Any input whatsoever is appreciated.

Comment: So you just pester internet strangers? ;-) Actually fixing your store would be the best approach, after all you will need to get updates etc.? Maybe have a look at [Distribute offline apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-offline-apps)

Comment: @Seth Well, not to put too fine a point on it, but uh.. yea haha. I figured it'd be sort of a win/win, I can get some good intel and the answering user can get some reputation. I will have a look at that post too, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

As the Sway app has no off line features anymore I would go for using the web site directly instead.